# Json key/value incorrectly formatted

Tags: swift, post, alamofire

Trying to login to a web service as such:

```
let parameters: Parameters = [
            "Password":password,
            "Username":username
        ]

        var headers:HTTPHeaders = commonHeaders()
        headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json;charset=UTF-8"

        Alamofire.request(url!, method:.post, parameters:parameters, headers:headers).responseJSON { response in

        ....

        }
```

Somehow, my parameters end up on the server side as

```
"Username=xxx&Password=yyy"
```

where

```
{"Username":"xxx","Password":"yyy"}
```

is expected

This must be something simple, but I hope you can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the type of encoding you want your parameters to be in your request, Default is .URLEncoding. So, your parameters are going like **"Username=xxx&Password=yyy"**(appended into url)

Add the parameter json encoding to your request:

```
Alamofire.request(url!, method:.post, parameters:parameters, headers:headers, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
```

Comment: Thank you agent smith. I was pretty new to Alamofire. Here's some more background that I found very useful: https://github.com/Moya/Moya/issues/1309